# Troubleshooting openDialog() Extendscript code

Tags: javascript, extendscript

I'm trying to write an openDialog() extendscript code that filters the selectable file types to only csv files on a mac. I was directed to the code here which does what I'm asking:  [Link](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/80003af709375bc36fc2ea19933878635ecb751b/ExtendScript-Toolkit/Samples/javascript/SnpXMLTreeView.jsx#L446)

I've written mostly the same thing, and the panel opens and allows me to select a file, but for some reason the filter doesn't work.

Here's what I have written:

```
// target the active Premiere Pro project
var activeSequence = app.project.activeSequence;

// import the CSV file
var file = File.openDialog("Select a CSV file to import.", fileFilter);
if (file) {
file.open("r");
var data = file.read();
file.close();
}

//This is the filter used by the openDialog function
function fileFilter(file){

index = file.name.lastIndexOf(".");
ext = file.name.substring(index + 1);

if(ext == "xml" || ext == "XML"){
return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Can anyone see what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the code from the link and it works fine for me.

Here is my a bit shortened version of the same code:

```
var file = File.openDialog("Select a CSV file to import", fileFilter);

function fileFilter(file) {
    if (!file instanceof Folder) return true;
    if (file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase() == 'csv') return true;
    return false;
}
```

Just in case, on Windows it works much simplier:

```
var file = File.openDialog("Select a CSV file to import.", "*.csv");
```